# Deep-linking into Spotify app

Tags: spotify

I’m having trouble finding documentation on Stack Overflow and on the Spotify Developers site around Deep-linking into a Spotify app from an external resource (i.e. a webpage). Can you provide a sample URI that would be used for an app with the name “mymusicapp”?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A URI for your app would be:

`spotify:app:mymusicapp`

To deep link, just keep going:

`spotify:app:mymusicapp:artist:Coldplay`

If you do that, the `ARGUMENTSCHANGED` event will fire on the `application` object.

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi();
var models = sp.require('$api/models');

models.application.observe(models.EVENT.ARGUMENTSCHANGED, function() {
    console.log(application.arguments);
});
```

For more information, see the [Application class documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/2edfee4d46.html).

Comment: Awesome! Very helpful, this should give me what I need for a user that has Spotify installed. However, is there a way to use open.spotify.com to accomplish the same thing?

Maybe something like "http://open.spotify.com/app/mymusicapp?arguments=artist:coldplay

(I'm trying to handle users without Spotify already installed)

Comment: The key-value parameters are mapped to URL in the same fashion. The URL would be: open.spotify.com/app/mymusicapp/artist/coldplay

Comment: The link to Spotify docs is dead x_X

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question? https://web.archive.org/web/20110705223657/http://www.spotify.com/se/blog/archives/2008/01/14/linking-to-spotify/

There is also the Web api which can be useful for finding the links: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/

Comment: That was helpful; I've figured out how to use open.spotify.com to open an app: http://open.spotify.com/app/soundrop

Comment: the first link is dead: 404

Comment: Updated the link using the wayback machine. Though I'm not sure if it is supported anymore.