# How to create Spotify deep link with my app as source

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, deep-linking

For example, `deepLink` equal to `spotify:app:com.example.name:playlist:37i9dQZEVXbdGwWzuKJrad` like old example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12369149/5894542). It just open Spotify, without target playlist. Can we append source app to `spotify:playlist:37i9dQZEVXbdGwWzuKJrad`?

In case of the `branchLink` browser opens.

```
val deepLink = "spotify:app:${context.packageName}:${entityType.argument}:${model.itemId}"
val spotifyContent = "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/${model.itemId}"
val branchLink = "https://spotify.link/content_linking?~campaign=${context.packageName}&\$deeplink_path=$spotifyContent&\$fallback_url=" + spotifyContent

val nativeIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(deepLink))
val webIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(branchLink))
```

Answer (score 0):

The referenced answer is very old. Maybe it had worked 10 years ago, but this format of URI `spotify:app:com.example.name:playlist:37i9dQZEVXbdGwWzuKJrad` definitely doesn't work now.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Spotify Content Linking](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/tutorials/content-linking) docs, the user needs to have the app installed and then this snippet will work:

```
final String spotifyContent = "https://open.spotify.com/album/0sNOF9WDwhWunNAHPD3Baj";
final String branchLink = "https://spotify.link/content_linking?~campaign=" + context.getPackageName() + "&$deeplink_path=" + spotifyContent + "&$fallback_url=" + spotifyContent;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(branchLink));
startActivity(intent);
```